# Error in Flutter unknown Error in iOS build, occurred after Flutter 2 and XCode 12.5 update

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

My App has was working and was going to release for Android and iOS, but few days ago after I update to Flutter 2.0 and XCode 12.5 "flutter run" fails in iOS only.
I downgraded XCode to 12.4 also still not working.

```
Development: Shivam Srivastava (67UX3WD5D5)"
Running pod install...                                              7.8s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           88.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2021-06-11 16:26:19.761 xcodebuild[968:9748]
    CFURLRequestSetHTTPCookieStorageAcceptPolicy_block_invoke: no longer
    implemented and should not be called
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    lib/widgets/PdfRender.dart:14:8: Error: Error when reading
    '../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/pdf_render-1.0.11/lib/p
    df_render_widgets2.dart': No such file or directory
    import 'package:pdf_render/pdf_render_widgets2.dart';
```

Comment: I think you need to update  AppFramework.plist deployment target in ios folder. I faced the issue before . Podspec file should be deleted and use flutter clean. Pod repo update then Be sure you updated deployment target on AppFramework.plist  and Info.plist. It should work.

Comment: I re-created project  with latest flutter and xcode, i tried delete podfile, pods and use pod init,install, update mutiple times didnt worked, question updated with podfile

Comment: SOLVED, package upgrade and new package config to be updated in project

Answer (score 0):

run **pod update** that worked for me there are packages that need to be updated.
the same thing happened my app was not building i run **flutter clean** then **flutter pub get** then pod update that solved it for me.

Comment: tried not working , tried all basic things, pod update, checked certificates, created new project from scratch

Comment: lib/widgets/PdfRender.dart:14:8 what is the code error at this line

Comment: I think its not relevant this second line error keeps changing, failed to build app causes continues error

Answer (score 0):

My pod file looks like this and works perfectly

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
   flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.3'
     config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
     config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
             '$(inherited)',
     # dart: PermissionGroup.camera
     'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',

     # dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
     'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',

     # dart: PermissionGroup.photos
     'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',

     # dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
     'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',

     # dart: PermissionGroup.notification
     'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',

     ]
   end
   installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
       config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
   end
 end
end


# target 'ImageNotification' do
#   use_frameworks!
#
#   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
# end
```